Finding the Lipschitz constant by maximizing function
I am trying to find the Lipschitz constant for $g(t,u)=2t^2u^2+|u|, 0\leq t\leq2 , 
 |u+1|\leq3.$ So what I tried was the normal approach of trying to simplify the inequality as:-
$$|g(t,u_1)-g(t,u_2)|\leq K|u_1-u_2|$$ and for this I substituted the value of $g(t,u)$ to get $$|2t^2u_1^2+|u_1|-2t^2u_2^2-|u_2||$$
$$ = |2t^2(u_1-u_2)(u_1+u_2)+|u_1|-|u_2|| $$
$$ \leq |2t^2(u_1-u_2)(u_1+u_2)+(u_1-u_2)|$$
$$ \leq |u_1-u_2||2t^2(u_1+u_2)+1|$$
Now this is where the issues start. From my understanding i need to maximize $|2t^2(u_1+u_2)+1|$ on the given region. Now according to me for this we can directly substitute both $u_1$ and $u_2$ as $-4$ and $t$ as $2$ and this would give 63 as the value. But other approach could be to further simplify using triangle inequality and then getting $ \leq|2t^2(u_1+u_2)|+|1|$ and now maximizing it to evaluate to $65$. On the other hand, my professor says you can't put $u_1$ and $u_2$ as $-4$ and you have to use $2$ which would result in the value simply being 32. Who is correct? I know this sounds more of like an homework problem but I am really confused now as to how to go about maximizing functions for Lipschitz constant. Thank you so much!

Keep in mind that different inequalities give different bounds. Using the „best“ sequence of inequalities can be a non-trivial problem, I‘d argue.

Hmm so how to decide? I also don't understand my professor's reasoning? Like isn't the whole point finding the supremum. So why won't we maximize that thing if it is in bounds?

Hint: Try plotting the function $g(t,u)$. You will see that $g$'s derivative is maximised on the boundary (and hence this must be its Lipschitz constant).

i don't really understand how would that work. I tried graphing this but the boundary is unclear to me. Also it is not always possible to graph and see right? I was hoping for a more "algebraic" solution rather than geometric
